# How to rollback the table when status is active and delete when status is pending?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

When i am inserting the item in cart list and makes the cart pending, the items present in the cart should be removed and cart will empty and later if i active that cart by going in Pending list and click on active button,  the existing item should be added in the cart item and when checkout it will clear the cart.

but In my case when i m trying to insert the second cart item, it's inserting the item in the existing cart again and not creating the new cart.

I used this query, because i don't know how to use `turncate` for this condition.

```
String query= "Select CART.CART_ID, CART.prod_id,CART.Index_id,CART.Barcode,CART.Amount,CART.Grand_Total,CART.Quantity,CART.Price,CART.status,PendingCart.P_ID,PendingCart.status,PendingCart.Created_Date,PRODUCT.Product_Price,Prod_quantity,PRODUCT.Price_Type,PRODUCT.Item_Name,PRODUCT.Image,PRODUCT.CGST,PRODUCT.SGST from PRODUCT  join CART ON CART.prod_id= PRODUCT.prod_id inner join PendingCart ON PendingCart.Index_id = CART.Index_id where CART.Index_Id= PENDINGCART.Index_id AND PendingCart.status = CART.status";


          private void AddToCart(){
            QTY= Float.parseFloat( edtQty.getText().toString());
            rate= Float.parseFloat( edtRate.getText().toString());
            Amount = Float.parseFloat( edtAmount.getText().toString() );
            unit = UnitType.getText().toString();
            Name = edtname.getText().toString();
            P_id = Integer.parseInt( rowId.getText().toString() );
            UnitType.getText().toString();
            BARCODE= txtbarcode.getText().toString();
            edtRate.clearFocus();
            edtRate.setText( String.valueOf( rate ) );
               AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                status= "active";
                if(!helper.isProductIdExists(P_id,status)){

                if (!helper.isStatusActive( status )){

                   helper.AddPendingCart( index_id,status);}
                    helper.AddInCart(Name,Amount,P_id,index_id,QTY,rate,BARCODE,status,Amt_with_gst_sgst );
                    txtcount.setText(Integer.toString(count));
                Toast.makeText( Home_Main.this,  "Product Added Successfully ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                   builder.setMessage( "Product already added to cart.Do you want to update?");


                    builder.setPositiveButton( "YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
                        helper.UpdateCartByProduct( P_id, QTY, Amount, Amt_with_cgst_sgst);
                        Toast.makeText( Home_Main.this, "Product updated Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                        // User clicked OK, so save the mSelectedItems results somewhere
                        // or return them to the component that opened the dialog
                    }
                    }).setNegativeButton( "NO",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {dialog.dismiss();}} );
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                    alertDialog.show();}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i was using wrong command Rollback is used where transaction performed manually or where it can be triggered automatically. i.e  your data bymistake has been deleted or you want a backup of your data.Don't use Rollback where you have master table and your second table like with master table in that case this is not possible.

I had solved this by creating pending table already when the user will add the cart pending id will create when the Cart_Activity will open pending item will create and item data will active until the i don't make the cart pending.That's how i solved this....If Anyone have this kind of problem...can msg me here